# VB.Net DirectorySecurity.GetAccessControl Error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to determine if I have write access to a directory on a remote server before I attempt to write to it, and this is the code I am using to do so:

```
Private Function Accessible(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

     Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(path)
     Dim ds As DirectorySecurity = di.GetAccessControl
      ...
```

The issue I am getting is that when I call di.GetAccessControl I get an unauthorized operation error. What I am wondering is if there is a way for me to either determine if I have the permissions to call GetAccessControl, or generally, a way to check access on a remote directory without it throwing an error. I think I will have to just throw the error but any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You should just handle the error.  Between the time of you checking if you have access then actually attempting that access, the permissions could change, and you'll wind up having to handle the error anyway.

Comment: That is true, I will just handle the error then